# need help can't find specific text with grep

Tags: regex, linux, search, grep

I have problem with `grep`. I need specific texts from my file **probe** 
matching all line like this :

```
<a href="/every_time_different_name">every_time_different_name</a>
```

I was trying to get it using

```
grep -o '<a href="/.*">.*</a>' probe
```

But problem is I got all text from file not this specifics text.

probe file: http://txt.do/doa21

Comment: in the other file you are spelling `different` as `diferent`

Comment: The probe file is all on one single line.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you are using is wrong because the first occurrence of `.*` will match the rest of the string. Try with:

```
grep -o '<a href="[^"]*">[^<]*</a>'
```